# How to add a new column to a table in mysql by query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, select, duplicates

I have a table in Mysql like this:

| studentname | Course |
| --- | --- |
| jon | C1 |
| David | C2 |
| wayne | C3 |
| jon | C3 |

I need to result be in a table like this:

| studentname | Course1 | Course2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jon | C1 | C3 |
| David | C2 |  |
| wayne | C3 |  |

It would be appreciated if any help me.
Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: why C3 in second column and not other whic is the criter for build ypru query

Comment: @scaisEdge just gave you a very good approach in his answer. Why are you trying to make each course a column in the first place? Think about it, if a student enrolls in 20 different courses are you gonna have a table with 21 columns? That just doesn't make sense, and it's a horrible practice. group_concat() is an excellent SQL function. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you need  only all the result for each student on a rows  you could use a group_concat eg:

```
SELECT studentname, group_concat(course) AS Courses
FROM my_table
GROUP BY studentname
```

Comment: @Alex_89  .. thanks for editing ..  and your clear suggestion at the OP  ..

Answer (score 0):

#### You can add the column with the following statement:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN Course2 CHAR(2)
```

Where `my_table` is the name of your table and `CHAR(2)` is the type of the column (you will probably want the same as `Course1`)

Have a look at the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

#### But doing it that way is totally wrong!

You are mixing concepts in your tables, what happens when a student enrolls for a third course? Or a fourth?

If your table is a junction table, see the answer posted by @scaisEdge.

Otherwise, if you are trying to store *all* the student information in one table, you should change the structure of your database to have:

A `student` table that stores student information, for example:

```
table student
  id  |    name    |      email       
  1   |  aragorn   |   aragorn@lotr.me
  2   |  gandalf   |   gandalf@lotr.me
...
```

Another table to store course information:

```
table course
  id  |      name    |    ....
  1   |     magic1   |    ....
  2   | swordmanship |    ....
```

And a junction table to store which students are enrolled in which courses:

```
table student_course
student_id    |    course_id
    1         |        1       // Gandalf is taking magic1
    2         |        2       // Aragorn is taking swordmanship
    1         |        2       // But Gandalf also is taking swordmanship
```

In this junction table `student_id` would be a foreign key to `student.id` and `course_id` a foreign key to `course.id`.

There is some good introductory information about the relational model in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model).

Comment: Or, if your table is already a junction table, then use scaisEdge's answer.